# Where to declare enum in c++ that is used by entire program, both in cpp and hpp files?

Tags: c++, enums

I have a program that performs simulations on networks.
all my classes and implementations are in the h file, and I'm trying to call my classes' functions(whose are in the h file) from main.cpp.
I use enumerations in my class, and the c'tor that's being called from main.cpp takes enum value. I keep getting errors because the cpp or h file doesn't know about these enumarations every time that I change the place of declaration.
1.should it be declared inside my class? outside? both in cpp and h file?
2.if I also want that methods of the class will be able to use the enumerated types, where should I put my declarations?
3. What's the right way to get the enumerated type from both the cpp file and from methods of the class?   I saw a few options such as ClassName::enumType, CLassName.enumType and so on.
this is my code structure:

```
    main.cpp
    #include...

    enum networkType {X,Y};

    int main(){
    //create instances of my class 
    network n = new network(X, ...);


    }


    networks.h
    //enum networkType {X, Y};      here?
    class network{

        enum networkType {X, Y};         //here?
    network::network(networkType x, ...) //c'tor
    ..
//members:
    networkType type_;

//functions that use the enumerated value
    void setNetworkType(networkType t);
    networkType getNetworkType();
...more methods
```

some of the errors I'm getting are - 
for the getter method - 
'networkType' does not name a type
 networkType network::getNetworkType()

Thanks.

Comment: `getNetworkType()` should probably be a `const` member function.

Comment: Even more importantly, make it an `enum class` to be type-safe.

Answer (score 1):

If you place the `enum` definition inside the class, the actual name of the enum is `network::networkType`.  You must use the full name any time you're outside the class scope (which includes the return type of a member function definition outside the class, unless you use trailing return types).

```
network::networkType network::getNetworkType()
{ return _type; }
```

(Note that if you also have `enum network` in main.cpp as you've shown, that's a *different* and incompatible type.)

Answer (score 0):

> 1.should it be declared inside my class? outside? both in cpp and h file?

`enum networkType {X,Y};` should definitely not be at global scope, because this would pollute global scope with `X` and `Y`. No matter what, declaration of enum should always (and only) be in the header file of the class.

Preferred C++11 declaration would be `enum class networkType {X, Y}` 
so `X` and `Y` will be scoped to `networkType`.

If `networkType` is mostly used by class `network`, I would put its declaration within `network` as follows:

```
class network{
    enum class type {X, Y};
};
```

No need to add prefix "network" to the enum name, because `type` is now scoped to `network`.

If you can't use C++11, I'd prefer this style:

```
class network{
    enum type {TYPE_X, TYPE_Y};
};
```

> 2.if I also want that methods of the class will be able to use the enumerated types, where should I put my declarations?

Declaration of methods and member variables can use nested types without prefix:

```
class network{
    enum class type {X, Y};
    network( type x, ... );
    type getNetworkType() const;  //< added const here, because method is only observer
    type _type;
}
```

When the implementation of a method is not inline, you have to add scope prefix:

```
network::network( network::type x, ... ){ 
    // within function body no scope prefix is needed:
    type y = x;
} 

network::type network::getNetworkType() const{ 
    return _type; 
}
```

Global functions have to use prefix in function header aswell as body:

```
network::type do_something( network::type x ){
    network::type y = x;
    return y;
}
```

> 3. What's the right way to get the enumerated type from both the cpp file and from methods of the class?

"From methods of the class" - see above.

Within .cpp file you have to use scope prefix aswell. While we are at it, don't use operator `new` by default. In most cases, you can (and should) create your objects on the stack. If you really need dynamic allocation, prefer smart pointers like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). Modern C++ code should almost never contain a `delete` and rarely a `new`.

```
int main(){
    // Prefer to use stack variables:
    network net( network::type::X );
    network::type theType = net.getNetworkType();

    // If you really need dynamic allocation:
    auto pnet = std::make_unique<network>( network::type::X );
    theType = pnet->getNetworkType();
}
```